# Best way to swap filenames

Tags: shell, shell-script, files, rename

I need to swap filenames of two files (`file` and `file_1`). I'm using the following code for it.

```
mv file .phfile
mv file_1 file
mv .phfile file
```

This works but is very buggy, It sometimes even results in loss of data. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Something you should be aware of and fear - any program that has an open file handle to either one of those files will retain the open file handle after the rename because it's pointing to the same inode that it had when it originally opened the file. Until all programs that have the files open close them, this will be the case and cause data corruption if you expect that renaming them 'breaks' any existing writer handles.

Comment: (1) “This works”?  No, this always destroys `file_1`.  (2) Most people who have two files would call them `file1` and `file2`.  10% of people would call them `file0` and `file1`.  1% of people would call them `andy` and `bob`, or `fred` and `barney`, or `fred` and `wilma`.  Using weird filenames makes it easy to make typos, like what the above obviously is, and for them to go unnoticed for ten years.  (3) Have you debugged the data loss that you have experienced?  Can you describe how it happens?  (3a) What sort of processing are the files subject to?  What’s the big picture?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) You should specify whether answers should assume that the two files are in the same directory, in different directories on the same filesystem, or on different filesystems. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using :

```bsh
file1=1stfile
file2=2ndfile

tempdir="$(mktemp -d)"

mv "$file1" "$tempdir/tmpfile" &&
mv "$file2" "$file1" &&
mv "$tempdir/tmpfile" "$file2" &&
rm -rf "$tempdir"
```

Comment: This copies+deletes the first file to `/tmp` and back (very slow for large files), unless the files were already in the same filesystem as `/tmp` (which is unlikely on many modern Linux systems where /tmp is on tmpfs, not disk.)

Answer (score 17):

The [`renameat2`](https://lwn.net/Articles/569134/) syscall on Linux systems, with the `RENAME_EXCHANGE` flag, should do exactly that, [this](https://gist.github.com/eatnumber1/f97ac7dad7b1f5a9721f) is a cli tool that claims to use it.

Comment: Here is the man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html

Comment: You don't need to compile and install an external tool to take advantage of `renameat2`. You can just JIT yourself a small tool using tcc. [See my answer for an example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/625900/353063).

Answer (score 7):

There's no low-level way to swap files in traditional Unix systems, so you need to use an intermediate temporary name. For robustness, make sure that the temporary name won't be used by any other program (so use `mktemp`) and that it's on the same filesystem as one of the files (otherwise the files would be needlessly copied instead of being just renamed).

```
swap_files () {
  tmp_name=$(TMPDIR=$(dirname -- "$1") mktemp) &&
  mv -f -- "$1" "$tmp_name" &&
  mv -f -- "$2" "$1" &&
  mv -f -- "$tmp_name" "$2"
}
swap_files file file_1
```

Beware that if an error occurs, the first file could still be under its temporary name, and the second file may or may not have been moved yet. If you need robustness in case of interruptions and crashes, a variant with two temporary names may be easier to recover from.

```
swap_files2 () {
  tmp_dir1=$(TMPDIR=$(dirname -- "$1") mktemp -d .swap_files.XXXXXXXXXXXX) &&
  tmp_dir2=$(TMPDIR=$(dirname -- "$2") mktemp -d .swap_files.XXXXXXXXXXXX) &&
  mv -f -- "$1" "$tmp_dir1/" &&
  mv -f -- "$2" "$tmp_dir2/" &&
  mv -f -- "$tmp_dir1/"* "$1" &&
  mv -f -- "$tmp_dir2/"* "$2" &&
  rmdir -- "$tmp_dir1" "$tmp_dir2"
}
```

If the temporary directories `.swap_files.????????????` are present on a reboot, it means that a file swap was interrupted by a power failure. Beware that it's possible that one of the files has already been moved into place and the other one hasn't, so the code here doesn't take care of all cases, it depends what kind of recovery you want.

[Modern Linux kernels](https://lwn.net/Articles/569134/) (since 3.15, relased in June 2014) have a system call to swap files: `renameat2(…, RENAME_EXCHANGE)`. However there doesn't seem to be a commonly available command line utility for it. Even glibc support was only added recently ([2.28](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/libc-alpha/2018-08/msg00003.html), released in August 2018).

Comment: "There's no low-level way to swap files" that doesn't seem to be true, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561609/102517

Comment: "However there doesn't seem to be a commonly available command line utility for it"  — If you count `tcc` - and you should - then there is. See my answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/625900/353063

Comment: @TendersMcChiken Tcc is commonly available in the sense of being available in many distributions, but not in the sense of being installed on a typical system. Even gcc is far more common. If you want to make a system call with commonly available tools, you can [do it in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032203/make-syscall-in-python), which is part of most default non-embedded unix installations these days.

Comment: The question didn't limit solutions to preinstalled utilities only so I went with the less constrictive interpretation. You most certainly can implement my solution in python if you so choose. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

A bit late to the party but **you can atomicly name-swap files in newer and older versions of Linux** by using `tcc` or `gcc` — both available in all major linux distributions — to *JIT* yourself a low-level tool that uses the correct kernel syscall and use that. No third-party tools needed:

```bash
swapname() {
    tcc -run - "$@" <<"CODE"
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h> 
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/syscall.h>
    
    // Ubuntu 18.04 does not define RENAME_EXCHANGE
    // Value obtained manually from '/usr/include/linux/fs.h'
    // You should switch to RENAME_EXCHANGE on modern systems
    // Just remove the following line, then remove the `local_`
    // prefix where it appears later in this function.
    int local_RENAME_EXCHANGE = (1 << 1);
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        if (argc != 3) { 
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not swap names. Usage: %s PATH1 PATH2\n", argv[0]);
            return 2; 
        }
        int r = syscall(
            SYS_renameat2,
            AT_FDCWD, argv[1],
            AT_FDCWD, argv[2], 
            local_RENAME_EXCHANGE
        );
        if (r < 0) {
            perror("Error: Could not swap names");
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
CODE
}
```

Running this bash function in the following manner will cleanly and atomically swaps filenames:

```bash
swapname "/path/to/file-1" "/path/to/file-2"
```

Note that `renameat2` with `RENAME_EXCHANGE` may require that both files be under the same filesystem mountpoint. See the error section in the man page that covers `renameat2` (i.e. [`rename(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/renameat2.2.en.html#EINVAL%7E2)) for more information.

##### Using GCC instead of TCC

If you prefer to use `gcc` instead of `tcc`, simply remove the line starting with `tcc -run ...` and add the following one in its place:

```
( EXEC="$(mktemp)" && gcc -x c - -o "$EXEC" && "$EXEC" "$@"; rm "$EXEC" ) <<"CODE"
```

Comment: This works really well on some file systems but not all. Probably unsurprising. On Window Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) for example, it works fine on the home directory but does not work on the automounted Windows files under /mnt/c etc. I imagine it won't work on quite a few network mounts either. Fortunately it is error checked. You get an 'INVALID ARGUMENT' error.

Comment: @BillSellers IIRC I don't believe `RENAME_EXCHANGE` can swap files if they live in different filesystems.

Comment: "No third-party tools needed" liar. You need `tcc`.

Comment: @b0fh Didn't lie. "No third-party tools" means that your distribution includes it in their official repositories; i.e. you don't need to fetch it from github, sourceforge or any other third party. With that said, you can certainly use `gcc` instead of `tcc` which is usually installed by default. See my edit above. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is more robust:

```
TMPFILE=tmp.$$
mv -- "$file1" $TMPFILE && mv -- "$file2" "$file1" && mv -- $TMPFILE "$file2"
```

quoting is for preventing problems with spaces in filenames, it uses a tmp file and && make the following command run only if the preceding ended successfully.

Comment: How's this? `file1=1stfile && file2=2ndfile && temp="$(mktemp -dp /mnt/sdcard)" 
&& mv "$file1" $temp && mv "$file2" "$file1" && mv $temp/"$file1" "$file2"`. It works. Thanks for your input.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9475497/1068546

Comment: using mktemp is good; nice find

Comment: but running a command with && in java with runtime.exec() don't work. :(

Comment: you have to quote your yourShellInput variable: *String yourShellInput = " \"echo hi && echo ho\" ";* or if ouy have double quotes in your command *String yourShellInput = " 'echo hi && echo ho' ";*

Comment: @Binoy Babu no please see my comment on your stackoverflow question for right way to do it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2633/discussion-between-binoy-babu-and-guido)

Comment: Note that by default `mktemp` directs to `/tmp/`, not to the current directory. If files are big, it may cause issues.

Comment: Why are there dashes in front of the first two commands, but not the last? Is this a mistake?

Comment: @shelvacu the double dash will protect against filenames starting with dash, that could be interpreted as commandline arguments; and yes it was missing from the last command (double dashes gently added by @Gilles)

Comment: @Gilles i rolled back you change using mktemp, because it is less robust (secure).

Comment: @guido On the contrary, using `tmp.$$` is insecure: it can be hijacked if the directory is writable by other users. `mktemp` takes care of this.

Comment: @Gilles i was not using `/tmp/tmp.$$`, but just `tmp.$$` to imply is was an home directory actually

Answer (score 0):

```
ln file1 file1.orig
mv file2 file1
mv file1.orig file2
```

Comment: (1) You should link related commands like this with `&&`, so if one command fails, the list terminates (and does not go on to do things that might be destructive.  For example, if your first command fails, and you go on to execute the second command, it will destroy `file1`.)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Your answer is pretty much the same as three previous answers, except for choice of filenames (which is inconsequential) and the use of ``ln`` instead of `mv` in the first command.  Why do you believe that this makes your answer better than the others? … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.